# computeVertexNormals doesn't work with model from JsonLoader

Tags: javascript, three.js

Model always display in FlatShading even when I already have `computeVertexNormals`. Model is exported without normal for optimize purpose, loaded in 3JS by JsonLoader, and converted to BufferGeometry.

Material is already `SmoothShading`. Please see this jsFiddle for better demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/2w9Lkjbm/6/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method

```
bufferGeometry.fromGeometry( geometry );
```

returns non-indexed `BufferGeometry`.

Also known as "triangle soup", non-indexed `BufferGeometry` has no shared vertices, so `computeVertexNormals()` sets all vertex normals to be the same as the face normal.

In your case, you need to call `computeVertexNormals()` on your original geometry -- before converting to `BufferGeometry`:

```
model.geometry.computeVertexNormals();

var bufferGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

bufferGeometry.fromGeometry( model.geometry );
```

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2w9Lkjbm/8/

three.js r.85

Comment: Actually my real case is I'm using Sea3D Loader - all mesh already are `BufferGeometry` when imported. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: You can try converting `BufferGeometry` to regular `Geometry` and calling `mergeVertices()` and `computeVertexNormals()`. Then convert back to `BufferGeometry`.