# Scale non-uniform resulting wrong imported vertex normals

Tags: three.js

### Scenario:

a. I have a default sphere in 3ds max

b. I scaled it down on X axis 10 times then exported to obj.

c. Import that scaled down sphere into 3JS, then I scale up X 10 times again.

d. I want the sphere look like step A - before it got scaled down - and I need to keep the imported vertex normals, not compute in 3JS

```
____
```

### Problem:

- The sphere even after scaled up still have the same vertex normal as when imported, imported vertex normal not update by scaling in 3JS, so lighting affect on sphere look not correct anymore. Please see these jsFiddle to understand what i'm talking about:

---

### JsFiddle to demonstrate:

1. Scaled down in Max and scaled up in 3JS, resulting wrong normals: http://jsfiddle.net/uury1jtt/5/
2. Default sphere from Max, not scale anything, no problem, just for demonstrate what should a correct vertex normal look like: http://jsfiddle.net/uury1jtt/4/

[image]
(the sphere is just for simplify sample, normally it can be any mesh)

---

### Reason:

I want to scale non-uniforms imported-mesh to reuse it in different shape

---

Please suggest some ideas on how can I get rid of this problem?  Every ideas is much appreciated!

Comment: You need to computeNormals. eg. `OBJ.children[0].geometry.computeVertexNormals();` [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2pha/uury1jtt/3/), but then you will have a shading problem. Why are you importing a sphere instead of using [SphereGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/geometries/SphereGeometry) or [SphereBufferGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/geometries/SphereBufferGeometry)?

Comment: This is just a sample scenario to prevent over-complicated example, normally that will be a mesh. I knew about `computeVertexNormal` but I have to use edited normals from Max so I can't use it.

Comment: Now I am not understanding the question... you already have the normals working from max, if you alter the model in THREE, the normals will need to be recalculated as I said, and now I see [WestLangley said in your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43624693/computevertexnormals-doesnt-work-with-model-from-jsonloader)

Comment: https://paroj.github.io/gltut/Illumination/Tut09%20Normal%20Transformation.html (look at figure 9.8).

Comment: none of your links work. You need to put the code in the question itself. And, do you need to import a sphere to repo the issue? If not then just use the built in sphere. [Please make the smallest example that repos the issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/349790/128511)

Comment: I have updated new link. About example code, actually there's no special code, just normal OBJ loader. I have to import the sphere, not using built-in because I want to keep the edited vertex normal exported from Max (again, sphere is just for example, normally it can be any mesh, I want to scale non-uniform in 3JS to reuse it in different shape)

Comment: Here's the problem as I understand it: You have a mesh with some normals. You scale it in 3DSMax (**this affects the normals**). You export the mesh with the scaled normals. You import the mesh into three.js, with the transformed normals. You try to "un-scale" the mesh, which affects the geometry, **but not the normals**. So really you need to figure out how to transform normals based on a scale input. Or maybe three.js should do this automatically, but that decision is above my rank.

Comment: Yeah, what's confusing me is what you do with normals inside of 3ds? Are they explicit and scale with your mesh, or do they get recalculated based on that scaled mesh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your normals are all squished in the x-direction. You'll have to dig deep into the `BufferGeometry`'s attributes and manually "stretch" those normals:

Try substituting your `onclick` callback in the JSFiddle with the following code:

```
document.getElementById("scaleButton").onclick = function(){
    object.scale.set(10,1,1);

    // Get the 'normal' attribute of the geometry
    var normals = object.children[0].geometry.getAttribute("normal");

    // Manually stretch the x-value of the normal by 10
    for(var i3 = 0; i3 < normals.length; i3 +=3){
        normals.array[i3] = normals.array[i3] * 10;
    }

    // Inform the renderer that the attribute was altered
    normals.needsUpdate = true;
}
```

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marquizzo/uury1jtt/6/)

Comment: Isn't this supposed to be handled with `normalMatrix`? I'm super confused with both the answer and the question. Those normals will go through a different transformation than whatever the scale is affecting (positions in this case). I'm afraid to go check, but i'd be surprised if a simple scale messes up the lighting calculations completely.

Comment: The normals seem wrong, i changed your fiddle to recalculate the vertex normals, instead of scaling and notice how the lighting changes. Original mesh shows the light on the wrong side. http://jsfiddle.net/brzk3pu0/. (turn to the side that receives less light, click the button, and notice that all the light goes away). Seems that you've scaled the mesh, without scaling the normals properly, so your squashed 3dsmax sphere, has the normals of a regular sphere. When you scale that up one axis, those normals scale as well.

Comment: What is the expected behavior here is beyond me. Why would you store something in a file only to transform it using some value from the file, why just not store everything as it should be in the file in the first place?

Comment: Yes, the normals "seem" wrong, but the original question specifically asks us not to recalculate the normals for him. He said he wants to export his custom normals, as manipulated in 3DS Max. 

It's not up to us to judge whether his exported file should be scaled or not; we don't know what he's building.

Comment: Ok, i guess i'm confused by the purpose of all this :) I'm still not sure where you got 10 from, this particular sphere happened to be scaled like that? Why not just have correct normals in the first place?